# ubuntu and Virtual PC

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-pc

Is there a way to install ubuntu 7.04-8.04 in VPC 2007? I can't do it because it just goes black. :-(

Comment: [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikekol/archive/2007/08/06/making-ubuntu-7-04-work-under-virtual-pc-2007.aspx) answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for VPC, but I would suggest getting the freely available VMWare Player - it runs both those versions of Ubuntu (and 8.1) fine. You'll need to download a small VMX (see [EasyVMX](http://www.easyvmx.com/)) from the web but that's fairly painless.

The only reason I keep VPC around is because it's the only one I know of that still runs OS/2 :-).

Comment: Why? I seem to recall seeing some very strange licensing stuff in there after Sun bought it out.

Comment: Specifically: "With the SCA, you give Sun permission to use your contribution under licenses other than the main VirtualBox license."

Comment: That's if you are developing for VirtualBox as it is open source.  If you are not making contributions to it why would it matter?

Comment: Agreed, if you're only using the software, not developing it, then what does it matter about contributions licensing?

Comment: Point taken. But then, I fail to see how VirtualBox is better. Sure, it's an open-source job but, as you say, "if you are not making contributions to it, why would it matter?". I think VMWare is far more polished.

Comment: VMWare also isn't free.  Unless you are going to use pre-created images. To me that makes VirtualBox WAY better.

Comment: VMWare Player *is* free (so is Server now, I think but I've never used it) and you can generate any image you want (see the link I provided). They're not prebuilt images but a web page that builds it to your spec.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't ever have much like with Virtual PC, to be honest. (It was developed with only various versions of Windows in mind, and from my experience there's always some sort of problem running any linux distro under it.) I would recommend VMWare Player, as suggested above, or alternatively [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), which has worked very well for me in the past (it runs certain linux distros best, though I can't remember which ones).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I have 7.10 installed in Virtual PC.

I don't quite remember but I think I also had an issue with 7.04, so I gave up.  I came back later when 7.10 came out and it installed from the ISO with no major issues (that I remember).